# Apparent paradox in Geometric probability problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose we have N particles in a box. We can consider these particles to be distinguishable, and move about the box randomly, like molecules of gas in a box. Suppose, the volume of this box is $V$.

I've been asked to find the probability that at a certain time, a small sub-volume $V_0$ does not have a single particle inside it.

**Approach 1 :**

The probability of a single particle being in region $V_0$, is simply $\frac{V_0}{V}$.

Hence the probability of $N$ particles being in the region, should be $(\frac{V_0}{V})^N$

Hence, the probability that there are no particles in that region must be :

$$P=1-(\frac{V_0}{V})^N$$

**Approach 2 :**

The probability of a single particle being in region $V_0$, is simply $\frac{V_0}{V}$.

Hence the probability of a single particle, not being in the region is simply $1-(\frac{V_0}{V})$

Hence, the probability that $N$ particles are not in that region would be given by :

$$P=[1-(\frac{V_0}{V})]^N$$

The two approaches get me to different answers, and different predictions. For example, according to the first one, as the number of particles increase, the probability increases. As for the second one, the probability decreases as the number of particles increase, which makes more physical sense.

However, I don't seem to understand, why there are two answers depending on the order in which I proceed, and which one is the correct one. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hint. Think through your two arguments for the experiment in which you flip three coins and want the probability of no heads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first approach yields the probability that the number of particles in the region is not $N$. There could be $N-1$ particles in the region, or $3$ particles in the region, though.

The second approach correctly yields the probability that the number of particles in the region is $0$.

Comment: +1 Yes.  You want each and every particle to be in the rest of the volume $V-V_0$, so the first calculation should be $\left[\frac{V-V_0}{V}\right]^n$, which is the same as the second calculation

Answer (score 1):

The event "no particle is in a region" is in general (except for the case $N=1$) not complementary to the event "all particles are in the region". Therefore the first approach fails for all $N>1$.